# Move animation of MKAnnotationView in MKMapView is not working propertly (iOS7)

Tags: ios, animation, mkmapview, mkannotation

I need to move `MKAnnotationView` in `MKMapView` from one position to another with animation. I'm using this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                         [_annot setCoordinate:newCoord];           
                 } completion:nil];
```

It is working fine, but when I move with map or zoom in or out annotation position is changing. Basically is not straight from one point to another. It look like `MKAnnotationView` is in another view than in the one responsible for moving map. Any tips for workaround? Starting to be depressed.

In `iOS6` is everything working as I expected.